Getting error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory" while executing testng suite
I was trying to execute simple TestNG script with new setup of Eclipse with Selenium.
Although with the same setup I am able to run other Java classes but when trying to run the TestNG suite I am getting this error.

Selenium version - 4.23.1
Eclipse Version  - 2024-06 (4.32.0)
Chrome version - 127.0.6533.120
Java version - Java 22

I tried after adding slf4j jars but no luck.
public class NewTest {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void openBrowser() { 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "D:\\Eclipse\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}

I got:
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.10.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.lambda$getLogger$0(Logger.java:30)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1710)
    at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:30)
    at org.testng.TestNG.<clinit>(TestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNGFactory7_9.createRemoteTestNG(RemoteTestNGFactory7_9.java:16)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 6 more

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Which slf4j jars? It makes a difference, you know.

This question is similar to: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@nitind I added these 2 jars in build path .
slf4j-jdk14-1.7.2
slf4j-api-2.1.0-alpha1

@Anish The solution given in the similar question is not working for me. That is from 2012, so I believe this issue came up with some later changes. Also I am facing this issue now with the latest version of eclipse.
